# Use lambda to refactor interface implementations?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

The following code is a common construct used with `spring` framework. The purpose it to provide configuration class that itself provides the required implementation classes, here `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`.

Is it possible/advisable to refactor this code using the new java 1.8 lambda expressions? If yes, how?

```
@Component
public class AsyncConfigurer extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {
    @Autowired
    private CustomService service;

    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
                service.call();
                logger.fatal(ex);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use a lambda for readability, not for optimization. I am not even sure that it will not provide exactly the same bytecode.

Comment: I think this is mainly a question of "style". People working a lot with Java 8 lambdas will tell you to change this code; people who don't like this new feature might ask you to not do it. 

My personal recommendation: go and ask those people that will be working with this code in the future. 

One reason for not porting: are you sure that you will never ever have to recompile your code with JDKs prior 1.8?

Comment: We, ok thanks for your opinion. Let me rephrase my question: how could lambda be used to refactor the above code? How would it look like? (as I could not find any examples regarding such types of code constructs).

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I don't think this is a duplicate, as your linked question is about `FunctionalInterfaces`, which mine is NOT about!

Comment: _"as I could not find any examples regarding such types of code constructs)"_ The official tutorial on lambda expressions is full of examples. A bit of digging and you could find how to do this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` is a functional interface, otherwise the answer provided by Duncan (and the duplicate) would not work.

Comment: Oh, you're correct. So far I thought a functional interface would have to be annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`, but I now learned this is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you want to do this is up to you; it's mostly a matter of style.

If you did, it would look like this:

```
@Override
public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  return (ex, method, params) -> {
    service.call();
    logger.fatal(ex);
  };
}
```